# Kivy - Key and Attribute Issues

Tags: python, kivy

As you can tell, I have a lot to learn. I don't seem to be catching on, so this problem is very similar to my last one I just posted. I want my button click to notify me it has been clicked already, but I get two errors. `KeyError: 'calendar_butt'` **and** `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'` .  I would like for the CalendarButt function to be referred to whenever the popup box opens and the `set_event` button is pressed

**Main .py File**

```
    from kivy.config import Config
    Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', False)
    Config.set('graphics', 'width', '800')
    Config.set('graphics', 'height', '600')

    from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.clock import Clock
    from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager, NoTransition

    from kivy.uix.button import ButtonBehavior, Button
    from kivy.uix.popup import Popup



    class CalendarButt(Button):

        def button_clicked(self):
            if self.ids.calendar_butt.state == 'down':
                print('Hello')

    class ScheduledPopup(Popup):
        pass

    class ButtonPopup(Popup):

        def schedule_event(self, *args):
            if self.ids.set_event.state == 'down':
                CalendarButt(text=self.ids.scheduled_event.text)
                print(self.ids.scheduled_event.text)

    class CalendarLayout(Screen):
        pass


    class January(Screen):
        pass


    class ManageScreens(ScreenManager):
        pass


    class Calendar(App):

        def build(self):
            return ManageScreens()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        Calendar().run()
```

**Main KV File**

```
#: import main calendar
#: import NoTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.NoTransition
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

#: include january.kv

<ScheduledPopup@Popup>:
    title: 'Event Scheduled'
    id: scheduled_popup
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: 'Event Scheduled.'

        Button:
            text: 'Close.'
            on_release: root.dismiss()


<ButtonPopup>:
    title: 'Set Events'
    title_align: 'center'
    auto_dismiss: False
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 400, 200

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        TextInput:
            multiline: True
            id: scheduled_event
            hint_text: "Something scheduled for this day..."

        BoxLayout:

            Button:
                id: set_event
                text: "Schedule"
                on_press: root.schedule_event()
                on_release: root.dismiss()

            Button:
                id: cancel
                text: "Cancel"
                on_release: root.dismiss()

<CustButton@Button>:
    size: 1, 1

<CalendarButt>:
    on_press: root.button_clicked()
    background_color: 12, 12, 12, 0.1
    font_name: 'Roboto-Thin'
    font_size: 20
    background_down: 'background_pressed.png'
    on_release: Factory.ButtonPopup().open()
```

**January.kv**

```
<ManageScreens>:
    transition: NoTransition()

    January:
        name: 'january'
        id: january

        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1

            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

        RelativeLayout:
            Label:
                text: "January"
                font_size: 20
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.88}

        GridLayout:
            pos_hint: {'top': 0.85}
            row_default_height: 75
            row_force_default: True
            cols: 7
            rows: 5
            spacing: 10
            padding: 10

            CalendarButt:
                text: ''

            CalendarButt:
                text: ''

            CalendarButt:
                text: '1'

            CalendarButt:
                text: '2'
```

Comment: This would be much easier for us to understand and help you if you posted a [mcve].

Comment: @JohnAnderson that's better?

Comment: Getting there. A [mcve] is something that I can copy, paste, and run on my system to see exactly the problem that you are seeing. Your post is still missing things (for example, I don't see the definition of your `Calendar` app).

Comment: @JohnAnderson Ah I understand. Should I just post the whole code then ? or majority

Comment: Only enough to reproduce the problem you are having.

Comment: @JohnAnderson this better?

Comment: If you copy both of the files in your post into an empty folder and run the `Main.py`, does it produce the errors you mention in your post?

Comment: I see that you create a rule for `CalendarButt`, but you never actually use it. Also, in your `button_clicked` method you have: `if self.ids.calendar_butt.state == 'down':`, but since you are already in the `CalendatButt` instance, you can simply do: `if self.state == 'down':`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson Yea, there's more to my code. I'll add more so you can test it and see the errors.

Comment: @JohnAnderson should be testable now. When I click the calendar button I'm not sure why I get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `button_clicked()` method, you are referencing `self.ids.calendar_butt`:

```
class CalendarButt(Button):

    def button_clicked(self):
        if self.ids.calendar_butt.state == 'down':
            print('Hello')
```

Two problems with this.

First, you have not defined any `ids` in `CalendarButt`. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#ids) for details about `ids`. Since there are no `ids`, the `self.ids.calendar_butt` throws the error you are seeing. If you scroll up on the error messages that get displayed, you should see a `KeyError: 'calendar_butt'` near the start of the error.

Second, since `button_clicked()` is a method in `CalendarButt`, the instance of `CalendarButt` is simply `self`, so your code should be:

```
class CalendarButt(Button):

    def button_clicked(self):
        if self.state == 'down':
            print('Hello')
```

With the above change, your code seems to work.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out after I learned a bit more in a book. Thanks a bunch though you are always a help